# Set value of combo box in AppleScript not saving

Tags: applescript

I am setting a value of a Combo Box using AppleScript. I can see the value is over there, but when I leave the table row, it does not store the value.

This is how I am setting it:

```
set value of combo box 1 of scroll area 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window 1 to str
```

On the application I can see it was correctly set, but if I leave the row, it is not stored. This commando is inside a table loop:

```
repeat with aRow in rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window 1
select aRow
set value of combo box 1 of scroll area 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window 1 to str
end repeat
```

Using the Element Inspector, I can see there is an action called Confirm on this combobox, maybe I need to call it? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Call the action "confirm" like this: `tell the combo box 1 of... to perform action "AXConfirm"`.

Comment: @CJK it does call the AXConfirm, but still doesn't save the data, any other idea? I tried pressing enter too, but didnt work